# Validation accuracy not increasing, overfitting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I created a simple LSTM model but my validation accuracy always revolves around 50 no matter how many epochs I use. Here's how it looks compared to training accuracy:

```
Epoch 15/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.9408 - accuracy: 0.7999 - val_loss: 3.5255 - val_accuracy: 0.5190
Epoch 16/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.8724 - accuracy: 0.8080 - val_loss: 3.6279 - val_accuracy: 0.5127
Epoch 17/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.8041 - accuracy: 0.8177 - val_loss: 3.6627 - val_accuracy: 0.5158
Epoch 18/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.7377 - accuracy: 0.8297 - val_loss: 3.7247 - val_accuracy: 0.5140
Epoch 19/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6680 - accuracy: 0.8431 - val_loss: 3.8000 - val_accuracy: 0.5144
Epoch 20/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.6036 - accuracy: 0.8578 - val_loss: 3.9164 - val_accuracy: 0.5051
Epoch 21/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.5460 - accuracy: 0.8715 - val_loss: 3.9832 - val_accuracy: 0.5089
Epoch 22/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4830 - accuracy: 0.8872 - val_loss: 4.0284 - val_accuracy: 0.5095
Epoch 23/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.4277 - accuracy: 0.9019 - val_loss: 4.1428 - val_accuracy: 0.5067
Epoch 24/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.3760 - accuracy: 0.9169 - val_loss: 4.1972 - val_accuracy: 0.5069
Epoch 25/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.3319 - accuracy: 0.9275 - val_loss: 4.2494 - val_accuracy: 0.5047
Epoch 26/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.2883 - accuracy: 0.9406 - val_loss: 4.3047 - val_accuracy: 0.5075
Epoch 27/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.2471 - accuracy: 0.9507 - val_loss: 4.3822 - val_accuracy: 0.5063
Epoch 28/50
2527/2527 [==============================] - 22s 9ms/step - loss: 0.2131 - accuracy: 0.9592 - val_loss: 4.4553 - val_accuracy: 0.5071
```

I think it might be overfitting but I have doubts about `validation_split` function that Keras provides. Does it even shuffle the data?

Anyways, here's my full code from start, even how I take input so u can tell me how I can modify it, from batch size to last nodes size etc. Please take a look and tell me how it can be optimised so my validation accuracy can improve.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 50
LSTM_NODES =256
NUM_SENTENCES = 3000
MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH = 50
MAX_NUM_WORDS = 3000
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 100

input_sentences = []
output_sentences = []
output_sentences_inputs = []

count = 0
for line in open(r'/content/drive/My Drive/TEMPPP/123.txt', encoding="utf-8"):
    count += 1

    if count > NUM_SENTENCES:
        break

    if '\t' not in line:
        continue

    input_sentence, output = line.rstrip().split('\t')

    output_sentence = output + ' <eos>'
    output_sentence_input = '<sos> ' + output

    input_sentences.append(input_sentence)
    output_sentences.append(output_sentence)
    output_sentences_inputs.append(output_sentence_input)

input_tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NUM_WORDS)
input_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(input_sentences)
input_integer_seq = input_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(input_sentences)

word2idx_inputs = input_tokenizer.word_index

max_input_len = max(len(sen) for sen in input_integer_seq)

output_tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NUM_WORDS, filters='')
output_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(output_sentences + output_sentences_inputs)
output_integer_seq = output_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(output_sentences)
output_input_integer_seq = output_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(output_sentences_inputs)

word2idx_outputs = output_tokenizer.word_index

num_words_output = len(word2idx_outputs) + 1
max_out_len = max(len(sen) for sen in output_integer_seq)

encoder_input_sequences = pad_sequences(input_integer_seq, maxlen=max_input_len)
decoder_input_sequences = pad_sequences(output_input_integer_seq, maxlen=max_out_len, padding='post')

import numpy as np
read_dictionary = np.load('/content/drive/My Drive/TEMPPP/hinvec.npy',allow_pickle='TRUE').item()
num_words = min(MAX_NUM_WORDS, len(word2idx_inputs) + 1)
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((num_words, EMBEDDING_SIZE))
for word, index in word2idx_inputs.items():
    embedding_vector = read_dictionary.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[index] = embedding_vector

embedding_layer = Embedding(num_words, EMBEDDING_SIZE, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_input_len)

decoder_targets_one_hot = np.zeros((
        len(input_sentences),
        max_out_len,
        num_words_output
    ),
    dtype='float32'
)
decoder_output_sequences = pad_sequences(output_integer_seq, maxlen=max_out_len, padding='post')
for i, d in enumerate(decoder_output_sequences):
    for t, word in enumerate(d):
        decoder_targets_one_hot[i, t, word] = 1

encoder_inputs_placeholder = Input(shape=(max_input_len,))
x = embedding_layer(encoder_inputs_placeholder)
encoder = LSTM(LSTM_NODES, return_state=True)

encoder_outputs, h, c = encoder(x)
encoder_states = [h, c]

decoder_inputs_placeholder = Input(shape=(max_out_len,))

decoder_embedding = Embedding(num_words_output, LSTM_NODES)
decoder_inputs_x = decoder_embedding(decoder_inputs_placeholder)

decoder_lstm = LSTM(LSTM_NODES, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs_x, initial_state=encoder_states)

decoder_dense = Dense(num_words_output, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

import tensorflow as tf

starter_learning_rate = 0.1
end_learning_rate = 0.01
decay_steps = 2000
learning_rate_fn = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.PolynomialDecay(
    starter_learning_rate,
    decay_steps,
    end_learning_rate,
    power=0.5)

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate_fn, epsilon=1e-03, clipvalue=0.5)

model = Model([encoder_inputs_placeholder,
  decoder_inputs_placeholder],
  decoder_outputs)
model.compile(
    optimizer=opt,
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

history = model.fit(
    [encoder_input_sequences, decoder_input_sequences],
    decoder_targets_one_hot,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_split=0.1,
)
```

I tried to add dropout layer but I couldn't add it between LSTM layer and dense layer. And I have doubts about `validation_split`. I tried to split dataset in train_test_set and valid_test_set but count make it work and ended up sticking with `validation_split`. Im pretty sure this is case of overfitting but not able to deal with it.

Comment: From the documentation about `validation_split` in [`tf.keras.Model.fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit): "The validation data is selected from the last samples in the `x` and `y` data provided, before shuffling". You may want to shuffle the data first or do the validation split yourself. If the data was sorted, fixing this should help (e.g. if you had ten balanced classes you would be missing one whole class in training right now, and only validating on that one). Other than that, in addition to dropout you can try adding some regularization.

Comment: I read about that too but Im not expert with coding, im just following a tutorial but with my own dataset, so I was not able to split myself, can u give hints how I can do that and even add dropout and regularisation by looking at my code?

Comment: @jdehesa I even tried adding dropout_layer = Dropout(0.5) but when I added it between LSTM layer and dense layer, it didn't work, maybe because I need to pass LSTM output as its input and pass its output to dense layer, I couldn't get it to work, neither splitting dataset